# Java EE 6 WebService and CDI injection

Tags: web-services, java-ee-6, cdi

This is a clarification question I've got from a Java EE 5 migration. I'm currently developing a Java EE 6 web service packed in a WAR file, and I would like to know if it's possible to use CDI on it. I've seen some examples using the `@Stateless` annotation, which it's not possible to do in a WAR (as far as I know).

Current implementation:

```
@WebService
public class MyService{

    @Inject 
    HelloTeller teller:

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(){
        teller.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Note: The other approach would be to create an *ejbModule* specifically for this web-service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EE6, you should be able to use a SLSB as JAX-WS endpoint in a war. You can inject EJBs,  request scoped and application scoped beans from CDI.

Comment: I've tried but the injected field is always null. I could make it work in a separate pure-ejb-project, but not whitin a WAR.

Comment: Got an arquillian test or simple war/github project?

Comment: @Timoteo Ponce: do you have a beans.xml file in your WEB-INF directory? Without, CDI does not work. Adding this file people often forget...

Comment: Interesting, this approach fails in JBoss-7.0.1, but the same code runs perfectly in JBoss-7.1.1.

Comment: 7.0.1 was only web profile certified, 7.1 is full profile. That's your difference.