# Is @Inject into @WebService supposed to work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jax-ws, cdi

Given the following extremely simple example:

```
@Named
public class A {

}

@WebService
public class WebService {
  @Inject A a;

}
```

I cannot get the injection to work and a is always null. I have include beans.xml in the WAR file WEB-INF directory. This is strange because injecting @Resource or @PersistenceContext works. So what is the definitive answer on whether or not this is supposed to work and why (or why not)? Shouldn't this be an EXTREMELY simple use-case? I found these two answers on here but they don't really offer any insight to a solution.

[Injecting Managed Bean into Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526751/injecting-managed-bean-into-webservice)

[Java EE 6 WebService and CDI injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848549/java-ee-6-webservice-and-cdi-injection)

Further details:
Weblogic 11g with no additional 3rd party jars deployed in WEB-INF/lib or installed on server

Comment: WebLogic 11g does not support CDI out of the box. Where is your `@Inject` and `@Named` annotation from?

Comment: You are saying I would need to package a CDI implementation in my WAR file? I find it hard to believe that Weblogic 11g wouldn't already include a reference implementation by default. Can you back this up with any other sources? They are from javax.inject package.

Comment: WebLogic 11g is a Java EE 5 application server. CDI 1.0 has been added to the Java EE specs with Java EE 6. I do not know whether it is sufficient to add a CDI implementation to your project. You may give it a try but do not expect that everything will work properly... Btw, if you are not using any additional libraries beside the Java JDK and the WebLogic modules, then (I guess) your Code should not even Compile.

Comment: Annotate your webservice class with the `@javax.annotation.ManagedBean`... check if this work.